HttpRequestFailedWithClientError Azure Datafactory
ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http request failed with client error, status code 404 NotFound, please check your activity settings. If you configured a baseUrl that includes path, please make sure it ends with '/'.
Request URL: https://gyter.sharepoint.com/sites/czxzd/SecAB/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/casc/ytu/dasasda/BMCSL/htsdL.xlsx')/$value.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.,Source=System,'
I have tested the conenction in the source and sink, both are success.
Also, I am using GetBearer token, which is also successfull.

Are you using copy activity? or dataflow transformation?

I am using copy activity, the Test connection in source and the Sink is successful, but while debug, i am getting this error.


Make sure you have added additional header which will retrieve token from web activity.  Even if source and sink test successful, you may get above error, If you don't add additional header.
Add additional header using below in source dataset which is having http linked service:
Additional headers: @{concat('Authorization: Bearer ', activity('<Web-activity-name>').output.access_token)}


After adding Additional headers, debug the pipeline, it will execute successfully.

For more clarification you can refer   below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/794319/azure-data-factory-pipeline-copy-error-404

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/561367/adf-rest-api-bearer-token



Thanks a lot, but now it gives me a different error.
'ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithUnauthorizedError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http request failed with status code 401 Unauthorized, usually this is caused by invalid credentials, please check your activity settings'

Check this once.
